# Angular 5 services for data sharing

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an array of objects in service.ts file of my angular project. This array needs to be used in 3 different components both read and write and also a components HTML file will use it to generate a table. So, how do I access the array in HTML file since this is in a service singleton.
Thanks

Comment: If it is "service" than what is stopping you from injecting it where it is required?

Comment: How do use the same in components HTML file to create a table, after injection

Comment: Share your code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sagar, the only thing you need is inject in the constructor of the component your service. If you want to use in your .html , you need use a getter

```
get myVariable()
{
    return this.myService.myVariable;
}
//a setter in your component
set myVariable(value)
{
    this.myService.myVariable=value;
}
constructor(private myService:MyService){}

//in your .html, e.g.

{{myVariable|json}}
```

Comment: The same approach I have been trying but can't implement the setter function for an array that I have in service. Can you suggest how to do that?

Comment: I add a setter function in my answer (the setter function is in the component)